# Jackson XML: How to have different element names from list name?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

The name of the list is present in the elements that belong to it.

```
public class root {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = “Name”)
  private String name;

  @JsonProperty(“ItemList”)
  private list<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class item {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = “ItemName”)
  private String itemName;

  @JacksonXmlText
  private String value;
}
```

I get:

```
<root Name=“”>
  <ItemList>
    <ItemList ItemName=“”></ItemList>
  </ItemList>
</root>
```

I want:

```
<root Name=“”>
  <ItemList>
    <Item ItemName=“”></Item>
  </ItemList>
</root>
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

You must use annotations: [@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "ItemList")](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html) and [@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Item")](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlProperty.html)

Example:

```java
public class root {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "Name")
    public String name;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "ItemList")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Item")
    public List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

XML generated:

```xml
<root Name="123">
    <ItemList>
        <Item ItemName="ItemName">value</Item>
    </ItemList>
</root>
```